# Insert a node into a sorted linked list of integers such that the list still remains sorted with final members for next

Tags: java, linked-list

In Java, how would you write a method to insert a node into a sorted linked list of integers such that the list still remains sorted, if all the nodes have a final member variable for next so you cannot alter them?

Comment: So you have to alter node before the one you insert. So if it is at the begining is all good. Problem is if it is in the middle or the end. So you would have to recreate all the nodes before the inserted one. Can you do that? Anyway it is a strange problem.

Comment: One cannot insert in such a list, only aquire a new larger list. One would think in java SE of `List.subList(0, i)+item+List.subList(i)` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. I think you need to look into guava's immutable collections, to have a patching copy or such.

Comment: Are you implementing your own linked list or do you use `java.util.LinkedList`?

Answer (score 3):

When the next link is final:

The only theoretical way would be to add a new node *in front* of the list and shift the data:

```
void insertSorted(MyList list, int data) {
    list.head = new Node(0, list.head); // Insert in front;
    Node prior = list.head;
    // Invariant condition: prior points to a node (not null) and soon data >= prior.data
    Node current = prior.next;
    while (current != null) {
        if (data < current.data) {
            break;
        }
        prior.data = current.data; // Shift smaller
        prior = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    prior.data = data;
}

insert:      d
list.head:   a ; b ; c ; e ; f ; g
--------------------------------------
list.head:   X ; a ; b ; c ; e ; f ; g
             a <-´   |   |
                 b <-´   |
                     c <-´
                         d
```

Was it an interview question? It seems so academic.